# What is the best SVN client for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, software-rec, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free SVN client for Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/19278/free-svn-client-for-mac)

What is the best SVN client for Mac OS X? I used TortoiseSVN on Windows, but TortoiseSVN is not available for Mac OS X.

Comment: Also, *please* learn the difference between your computer hardware and operating system. You can install Windows on your Macbook Pro, just do that and continue using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @Daniel: No i'm not using window on Mac

Comment: That's what I meant. This question has *no connection at all* with the fact that you're using an MBP. It'd be the same for a Mac mini, or an iMac, or (gasp) a Hackintosh. The relevant information is that you're using Mac OS X.

Comment: question sounds subjective, but I use [SmartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html). It's good, but costs money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have heard only good things about [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) (I haven't tried it myself, moved all my projects to git):

[image]

You also have the command line `svn` installed already.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't free, I'm partial to Cornerstone. Seems worth the money to me.